# When deploying python warrant package with serverless I am getting error 'size of unzipped files bigger than 250 MB'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy a lambda function through serverless framework which contains python package warrant. But I am getting error that 'Unzipped size must be smaller than 250 MB'. I have virtual env in the same directory as serverless.yml. I am not sure how to exclude what as it has many items along with warrant. But in the requirements.txt I have only mentioned 'warrant'.

Comment: Can you add details about how you created the virtualenv? Have you looked into which paths are large by inspecting the virtualenv?

Comment: Thanks Jacques for replying. This is how I have created and set up virtual env.                              $ pip3 install virtualenv
$ cd my_project_folder
$ virtualenv venv --python=python3
$ source venv/bin/activate                                      Then I have installed warrant inside it.  Now it has bin,lib and include directory. lib/site-packages is the most large 115 mb

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure. That seems like you should be fine unless your code and files that you package up with it are more than 100MB somehow. I haven't used serverless.yml myself so I can't speak to that end.

Comment: Thank you. I have figured it out.

Comment: Congrats! If you have time, it would be helpful for the community if you wrote up your solution as an answer and accepted it. Then if other folks find this question, they aren't left wondering how you solved it :)